# How to setup eclipse CDT to cross compile the kernel for the Raspberry Pi

Tags: cross-compilation, ide

How do I setup eclipse CDT to cross compile the kernel for the Raspberry Pi?

Is it as simple as **File -> New -> Makefile Project with Existing Code**?

What else has to be considered?

Comment: it's very unlikely you'll be able to cross-compile kernel using Eclipse. might have better luck trying to use command line tools like `make`.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done if you use a distribution designed for
embedded development, such as my project Nard SDK
http://www.arbetsmyra.dyndns.org/nard/
(but there are others too!).

A short guide:

1. Follow the instructions at the website to build the example product.
2. When the example has been built successfully once; open Eclipse.
3. Menu: `File > Import > C/C++ > Existing Code as Makefile Project`
4. Set `Code Location` = /path/to/extracted/nard/
5. Set `Toolchain` = "`Cross GCC`"
6. Click "`Finish`"
7. Take a coffe, Eclipse will index the **big** tree...
8. In the Project Explorer you can find the kernel source in `nard > apps > linux-kernel > linux-kernel`
9. Hack away...
10. Rebuild the firmware with menu: `Project > Build Project`
11. The website has documentation for how to push your custom kernel/firmware to the target. You can likely setup Eclipse to run the necessary shell commands automatically.